# In javascript, how can I put the same excel formula in a range/column of cells but have the formula change based on the cell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I'm using xlsx-populate, but would be open to using anything. I want the same formula to be used in every cell in the column/range but the numbers of the formula to change based on the row number.

ie. the formula in cell D1 is =SUM(A1*B1), but in row 4 in cell D4 the formula in that cell is =SUM(A4*B4).

I think my function is very off(I don't know what to put in the function parameters, etc.)

```
    theNewSheet.range("D1:D9").forEach(function(cell, i) {
                        var celly = cell.row;
                        var cellFormula = "=SUM(A" + cellyNum + "*" + "B" + cellyNum + ")";       
                        cell.formula(cellFormula);
///formula in excel should look like =SUM(A?*B?), where "?" is the row number the cell is in

                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all at once.

```
var cellFormula = "=SUM(A1*B1)";       
theNewSheet.range("D1:D9").formula(cellFormula);
```

The row number should progress according to the row 1 through 9.

Comment: Wow... I didn't' know it progressed automatically, turned out to be such a simple answer, thanks a lot!!! Also I accidentally wrote ".function" instead of ".formula"

Comment: Thanks for the kudos and the tip on the correct operation. tbh, I've never used [tag:node.js] but this is a common operation for various [tag:excel] programming platforms.